# Video loop autoplay won't work on Chrome/safari (webkit bug)

Tags: javascript, video, webkit, autoplay, mediacontroller

Hi guys I am trying to have my video autoplay and loop in a slider but some how it's not playing on chrome and safari. I find out webkit browsers have a bug that stops the video autoplay function when it's restyled...

Here's the video and the page. (works on firefox)
http://dustintong.com/projects.html#ts

I think you have to re-trigger the .play()
Not sure what I did wrong. New to javascript...
Here's the code below.

JS

```
var myVideo = document.querySelector('video');
var mediaController = myVideo.controller;

mediaController.play();
```

HTML

```
<div id="video">
<video src="images/7-4s.mp4" autoplay loop muted> 
</video> </div>
```

Comment: In safari autoplay for video wont work.. We have to initiate play manually or by script.But in chrome it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In safari, autoplay works just fine.
If you put this `<video src="images/7-4s.mp4" autoplay loop muted>` you don't need any js.
You can try this plugin https://github.com/videojs/video.js

Comment: holy crap the plugin worked!! hope it's not increasing the page load time by a lot

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best solution to this is adding this script just after your video tag--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('videoid').play();
</script>
```

Abit cheesy but works well :)
You can also try setting preload attribute to true.

Comment: doesn't work. preload=true? can you clarify? I am new to JS

Comment: The preload attribute specifies if and how the developer thinks that the video should be loaded when the page loads.