# HTML video tag's autoplay property has no effect in chrome if click Refresh button?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I need to start playing video file automatically when my page is opened. I use  tag for that. Everything is Ok with Firefox (my version is 50, Windows 10). But if I open this page in Chrome (my version is 66.0.3359.139, Windows 10) it does not starts playing video. If I click Refresh button it also doesn't play it. But if I press F5 or Ctrl+F5 it starts playing.

Example page: http://136.243.19.144/test-video.php

Video Code:

```
<video autoplay loop controls>
     <source src="http://136.243.19.144/v/230518/4XFq546l.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

What is wrong with this simple code?

EDIT:

Solution: Just add "mute" attribute to video tag.
Found in [Video loop autoplay won't work on Chrome/safari (webkit bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422040/video-loop-autoplay-wont-work-on-chrome-safari-webkit-bug?rq=1)

Comment: I opened your example page in Chrome 65.0.3325.162 and the video auto-played for me.

Comment: chrome 66. no autoplay. check the link, please: https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/22/17150870/google-chrome-autoplay-videos-sound-mute-update

Comment: Amber, Article states that Chrome blocks videos that have sound. My video has no sound.